# How to check the initial message sent to paypal?

Tags: paypal, httprequest

I need to match the user who triggered the initial Http message sent to paypal, to the IPN i'm receiving on my backend when the transaction is completed. Since Paypal is unaware of my user database I'm looking for some kind of transaction ID.

the thing is, when a user clicks on a paypal hosted button, Paypal opens another window and processes the buyer login and every other payment steps there.

I've had a look at the URL of that new Paypal window and there is nothing  there that will also be stated on the IPN.

Is there a way to check the initial http message sent to paypal from my frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `custom` parameter to pass your own unique ID into the payment request.  This would then be returned in the same `custom` parameter included in IPN.

The field is literally called `custom` and you can pass anything you want in it up to 256 characters.

You should be able to add it as an additional hidden field in your HTML form for the hosted button.  If it doesn't pass as expected that way, though,  you'll need to use a non-hosted button.

Comment: Thanks Drew! Can you add more than one 'custom' parameter or is it limited to that one?

Comment: Just the one, but you could send a string of multiple parameters in that one field and then parse them out when it's returned to IPN.